# Running CPU Utilization command in Java in Linux

Tags: java, linux, cpu-usage

I am writing a Java program which will be run in a Linux machine. I wanted to get the CPU utilization of the system. For getting the cpu utilization of the machine I use the command :

```
top -bn 2 -d 0.01 | grep '^Cpu.s.' | tail -n 1 | gawk '{print $2+$4+$6}'
```

Then I call this command from the java code, but I do not get any output. Normal linux commands such as `ls` works for me.

My code is:

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         String s;
        Process p;
        try {
           p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -bn 2 -d 0.01 | grep '^Cpu.s.' | tail -n 1 | gawk '{print $2+$4+$6}'");


            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println("line: " + s);
             p.waitFor();
            System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue());
            p.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use pipes, you need run your command from within a shell:

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c",
      "top -bn 2 -d 0.01 | grep '^Cpu.s.' | tail -n 1 | gawk '{print $2+$4+$6}'");

p = b.start();
```

Also, please be aware that your command fails on a different locale. And the output of `top` may vary too.

Comment: Your method did work. However it did not print. I outputted it to a file and read the content of the file.

Comment: Well, since your command didn't work for me, I had to change it. It did print something, however. The the only change I made was this: `top -bn 2 -d 0.01 | grep -i 'cpu' | tail -n 1 | gawk '{print $2+$4+$6}'`